# PHPmailer SMTP domain level

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I should connect to an smtp authenticated server, then use a specific mailbox to send emails, because the stmp server is authenticated ad a level domain.

According to my provider, credentials are:

- Server authsmtp.domain.com
- User: smtp@domain.com
- Password: ***

But I want to send emails from myaccount@domain.com, not smtp@domain.com
How can I do that with PhpMailer? I don't have two user field in PhpMailer.

```
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth
$mail->SMTPSecure
$mail->Host
$mail->Port
$mail->Username
$mail->Password
```

Comment: So just update your credentials instead of providers

Comment: The user to connect to the mail server is smtp@domain.com, I can't use myaccount@domain.com to login. But i want to send emails from myaccount@.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The username and from or sender addresses are often treated separately, so you should have no trouble sending as a different user in the same domain if your mail server is configured to allow that. In PHPMailer the three properties are `Sender`, `From` and `Username`.